# add text after keyword in bash / shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am in the middle of a migration for PTR records from MSoft and I am adjusting the zonefiles for my needs. I have already prepared the zone files so they look like the following:

`snapo@jump:~/mike/10$ cat 21.128`

```
102                     [AGE:3630582]   1200    PTR     host1.domain.company.local.                      
69                      [AGE:3630774]   1200    PTR     host2.domain.compan2.local.                    
                        [AGE:3630762]   1200    PTR     host2.domain.company.local.                          
80                      [AGE:3630774]   1200    PTR     hostXX.domain.company.local.
```

so I have the filename as variable `x` and I want to achieve the output of the text file to be like this with awk (because I don't think that there is another way in bash). Please no php/python/perl answers, because the script will need to run on different systems and the only language that is supposed to be installed is bash.
Because this is a merge from multiple PTR zones to one, I would have to edit the zone file to look like this:

```
102.21.128                        [AGE:3630582]   1200    PTR     host1.domain.company.local.                      
69.21.128                         [AGE:3630774]   1200    PTR     host2.domain.compan2.local.                    
21.128                            [AGE:3630762]   1200    PTR     host2.domain.company.local.                          
80.21.128                         [AGE:3630774]   1200    PTR     hostXX.domain.company.local.
```

It is also possible that there is no number in the first row "empty" , then it should add it without a dot in front. Do you have an awk sample or any other sample (cut , grep , head, tail, sed)?
Command should replace the strings in the existing file or with a pipe in the output file `> editedtextfile.txt` or similar.

Comment: If you expect the only "language" to be installed is bash, why do you expect awk to be available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sed:

```
 sed 's/^[^[:space:]]\+/&.21.128/' filename
```

Treating the input as plain text has the advantage of keeping the formatting intact.

For the edited question, this can be expanded to

```
sed 's/^[^[:space:]]\+/&.21.128/; s/^[[:space:]]/21.128&/' filename
```

**Addendum:** If you don't want to repeat the inserted data in the code, then

```
sed 's/^[^[:space:]]*/&\n21.128/; s/^\n//; s/\n/./' filename
```

is another approach that uses a little more trickery: It inserts a marker before the new data, removes the marker if there is nothing before it and otherwise replaces it with a dot.

**Addendum 2:** Using shell variables with sed code is a little tricky and potentially dangerous (because of code injection). If the variable comes from a trustworthy source and is known to not contain any metacharacters, then it is possible to write

```
sed "s/^[^[:space:]]*/&\n$variable/; s/^\n//; s/\n/./" filename
```

as @triplee points out in the comments. If `$variable` contains slashes but no other metacharacters and a character is known that it does not contain, then it is possible to use a different delimiter for the `s` command:

```
sed "s@^[^[:space:]]*@&\n$variable@; s/^\n//; s/\n/./" filename
```

(if it is known that `$variable` does not contain the character `@`).

If none of this is the case, deeper magic is required. For example, if `$variable` is known to be a single line (I suspect that this is the case because otherwise the transformation makes little sense), then it is possible to write

```
(echo "$variable"; cat filename) | sed '1 { h; d; }; s/^[^[:space:]]*/&\n/; G; s/\(.*\n\)\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/; s/^\n//; s/\n/./'
```

This feeds the variable to sed as first line of the input, and then works as follows:

```
1 { h; d; }                        # first line: hold, don't print
s/^[^[:space:]]*/&\n/              # after that: Insert marker as before
G                                  # fetch variable from the hold buffer
s/\(.*\n\)\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/   # move it to the right place
s/^\n//                            # rest as before.
s/\n/./
```

However, at this point you may want to consider using awk instead, which has better facilities to deal with shell variables (that is to say, you can use them without treating them as code):

```
awk -v var="$variable" '{ n = match($0, /[ \t]/); print substr($0, 1, n - 1) (n <= 1 ? "" : ".") var substr($0, n) }' filename
```

The `-v var="$variable"` makes a variable `var` known to the awk code that has the value of `$variable"`, and the awk code then works as follows:

```
{
  # find the first space or tab in the line (0 if none)
  # (I would use [[:space:]] here, but there are commonly shipped versions
  # of mawk that don't understand POSIX character classes, so for portability
  # I resort to [ \t])
  n = match($0, /[ \t]/)

  # assemble output line accordingly and print it.
  print substr($0, 1, n - 1) (n <= 1 ? "" : ".") var substr($0, n)
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the answer, the only problem i still have (forgot to add this to my text) is that some lines are empty.

Comment: is there a way to replace .21.128 and 21.128 in the sed command with a variable? i have it in a for while loop....

Comment: There is indeed, but then you need to switch from single quotes to double, `sed "s/^[^[:space:]]*/&\n$variable/;s/^\n//;s/\n/./" filename` and luckily, there are no shell metacharacters here which need to be escaped inside double quotes (though doubling the backslashes would not be entirely wrong).

Comment: i am still getting errors with this sed command `sed "s/^[^[:space:]]*/&\n$x/;s/^\n//;s/\n/./" $x;`   Error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'` it seems that the variable is not used or does not work... or cant be interpreted by sed...

Comment: What is the value of `$x`? When substituting variables into sed code (or any code, really), care must be taken because sed has no way to know what you want to be interpreted as data and what as code. If `$x` contains slashes, for example, this would mess up the structure of the sed code.

Comment: I edited in some ways to deal with this problem in sed, but the truth is that once shell variables are involved, awk is usually the better tool. So I also edited in a way to do it with awk, which is the one you probably want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F" " '{print $1".21.128\t" $2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5}' $1
```

Comment: No need for `-F" "` since this is default separator for  `awk`.  Also use code tag in your post.